# SQL server sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats Remote scan in query plan

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a query in db A which shows the index fragmentation level and recent rebuilt or re-organised status, it cross apply a function B in db C, A and C are on the same instance.

Function B is:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[B]
(
@db_id int
,@object_id int
,@index_id int
,@partition_number int
,@mode varchar (20)
)
returns @results TABLE (
[database_id] [smallint] NULL,
[object_id] [int] NULL,
[index_id] [int] NULL,
[partition_number] [int] NULL,
[index_type_desc] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
[alloc_unit_type_desc] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
[index_depth] [tinyint] NULL,
[index_level] [tinyint] NULL,
[avg_fragmentation_in_percent] [float] NULL,
[fragment_count] [bigint] NULL,
[avg_fragment_size_in_pages] [float] NULL,
[page_count] [bigint] NULL,
[avg_page_space_used_in_percent] [float] NULL,
[record_count] [bigint] NULL,
[ghost_record_count] [bigint] NULL,
[version_ghost_record_count] [bigint] NULL,
[min_record_size_in_bytes] [int] NULL,
[max_record_size_in_bytes] [int] NULL,
[avg_record_size_in_bytes] [float] NULL,
[forwarded_record_count] [bigint] NULL,
[compressed_page_count] [bigint] NULL
) 
begin 
insert into @results 
select *
from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (@db_id, @object_id, @index_id ,@partition_number 
,@mode )

return 
end
```

This query takes a long time to execute. I read the query plan, the plan contains a "Remote Scan". I don't understand why is that.

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Comment: What mode are you calling `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` in?

Comment: Hi Martin, I am not sure what "mode" do you mean. I called it:    CROSS APPLY 
 C.dbo.[B] (db_id(@DBName), l.object_id, l.[index_id],null,'LIMITED' ) dmv

Comment: and today, when I ran it, it returns result in 3 seconds.